# Не понимаю, как вывести значения в новой строке

Tags: python-3.x

Я только начинаю пользоваться питоном. Мне задали с помощью списочных выражений(list comprehension) написать программу для построения горизонтальных столбчатых диаграмм с помощью символа плюсики.
Ввод:
3 7 1 10 8
Результат:

```
+++

+++++++

+

++++++++++

++++++++
```

---

мой код:

```
a_input = input().split()
a = [int(i) * '*' for i in a_input]
print(a)
```

У меня выводятся звёздочки в строчку, а мне надо в столбик. Помогите пожалуйста разобрать, если ещё объясните как пользоваться функцией, которой воспользовались, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` печатает построчно. Значения гистограммы - столбики. Значит нужно сначала создать матрицу из точек/пробелов и потом выводить ее поэлементно. Т.е. из чисел, например, 1 3 4 1 2 1 1 матрица должна получиться примерно так:

```
m = [["  +    "],
     [" ++    "],
     [" ++ +  "],
     ["+++++++"]]
```

Т.к. это учебная задача, то код приводить не буду.